# Compare array variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

when trying to run the following code:

```
var pvals = new Array();
pvals = "[" + $("#upcheck").val() + "]";
pvals = $.parseJSON(pvals);
pvals = pvals.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id) } );

for (var i = 0; pvals.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
       //do something
    } else {
        if (pvals[i].id == pvals[i - 1].id) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Firebug within Firefox shows the following message "TypeError: pvals[(i - 1)] is undefined"
Can anyone please help? I have defined pvals as an array.

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: i am getting the json from a textbox, i have updated the code above to what im using and this is the json in the textbox: {"id": "3", "field": "name", "previous": "john"},{"id": "3", "field": "ext", "previous": "1234"},{"id": "2", "field": "name", "previous": "bill"}

Comment: Please check my the last part of my [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415495/compare-array-variables/23415536#23415536). You're running out of bounds when `i == 4`.

Comment: it still doesnt like if (pvals[i].id == pvals[i - 1].id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you define `pvals` doesn't work. You need to escape the quotes.

```
pvals = '[{"id": "3", "field": "name", "previous": "john"},{"id": "3", "field": "ext", "previous": "1234"},{"id": "2", "field": "name", "previous": "bill"}]';
```

Alternatively, just use it as an array, and forget the `JSON.parse()`:

```
pvals = [{"id": "3", "field": "name", "previous": "john"},{"id": "3", "field": "ext", "previous": "1234"},{"id": "2", "field": "name", "previous": "bill"}];
```

Also, your for loop doesn't end unless `pvals.length` becomes `0` or `false`. You should change that line to `for (var i = 0; i < pvals.length; i++) {`, which will fix your *undefined* error since you were trying to access an array index that was out of bounds.

**Edit:** The last statement still holds true based on OP's edited question.

Comment: No; use an array literal.

Comment: We're not sure if the data he's actually getting is in the form of JSON, or a JSON string.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Haha, fubar'ed there.. I meant "**Javascript Object**, or a JSON string". Thanks @JoeFrambach

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
pvals = '[{"id": "3", "field": "name", "previous": "john"},{"id": "3", "field": "ext", "previous": "1234"},{"id": "2", "field": "name", "previous": "bill"}]';
```

Also:

```
for (var i = 0; i<pvals.length; i++) { // if not loop doesnt stop
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a bit of sense to write json as a string, then immediately parse it.

Rather than using **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation as a string, just notate the object in javascript.

```
pvals = [{"id": "3", "field": "name", "previous": "john"},{"id": "3", "field": "ext", "previous": "1234"},{"id": "2", "field": "name", "previous": "bill"}];
```